# How to Perform Bubble Sort using Pointers

Tags: c, sorting, bubble-sort

I have written this code for Bubble Sort using Pointers, but I am getting errors like LVALUE required.

Here is my code. Please fix this code. I am getting error basically in swapping syntax. Please help

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void sort(int *a,int n);
void main()
{
    int a[20];
    int n,i;
    clrscr();
    printf("Program for BUBBLE SORT\n");
    printf("Enter the Number of ELements you want in Array\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter the Elements in UNSOTED ARRAY\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("The Unsorted ARRAY is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    sort(&a,n);
    getch();
}
void sort(int *a,int n)
{
    int i,temp,j;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n-i;j++)
        {
            if((*a+j)==(*a+j+1))
            {
                temp=*a+j;
                *a+j=*a+j+1;
                *a+j+1=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly - it's virtually unreadable in its present form.

Comment: ..."please fix this code"??

Comment: *Please fix this code.* No, you fix it. If you don't understand what "LVALUE required" means, ask about that (but search first, because I'm sure there are more than a few answers here on that already). We're here to help, but this isn't a coding service.

Answer (score 9):

Better make your swapping section like this:

```
temp = a[j];
a[j] = a[j+1];
a[j+1] = temp;
```

Especially if you're a beginner in C, fancy syntax with pointer math for simple array access doesn't help you understand your own code.

Also, you probably want to call your sorting function like this: `sort(a, n)`, because `a` already means `&a[0]` in C. If you start throwing more reference operators you'll end up accessing other memory than what you intend.

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing a couple of parenthesis:

```
if(*(a+j)==*(a+j+1))
{
    temp=*(a+j);
    *(a+j)=*(a+j+1);
    *(a+j+1)=temp;
}
```

They are needed because you want to add j to a, *then* to dereference that address.